# windbg to debug outlook addin at the dll function call level

Tags: .net, windows, dll, outlook, windbg

I have a third party addin in my MS Outlook 2010, and it is performing really slow. I need to figure out exactly where is the bottleneck. All I know is, the addin is made of dll(s), and functions inside the dll gets called, when I click on the plugin button. I have used a decompiling tool to break down the dll to see the class files inside. But, the project is too huge, and I am finding it difficult to trace the function calls in it. 
So, I thought if I can use WinDBG to trace the function calls in the debugging mode. Hence, I opened outlook.exe inside windbg, and in the dbg command window I gave the command 'g' to start debugging. After that I used the plugin inside outllook to do my work. But, in the windbg debug console I am not seeing any entry logging the call to the dll, and also, the function calls happening inside the dll are also not listed out. I am getting a log like this:

```
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
ModLoad: 74620000 74645000   C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.DLL
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
.
.
.
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(6dc.1064): Unknown exception - code e0000002 (first chance)
ReminderQueue: ProcessNotification: TABLE_ROW_ADDED
New reminder: Subject == test dbg ApptStartTime: Tue 10/28/2014 10:30 PM, Reminder Trigger: Tue 10/28/2014 10:15 PM
ReminderQueue: ProcessNotification: End<-----
```

The dll listed in the above log is not the third party dll I want to debug. I don't know why it is not getting listed, when I am using it, while the debugging is on. What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see the following issues in your approach:

- WinDbg is not really good in doing performance analysis. It is good in analyzing exceptions and crashes. You might want a performance analyzer like [WPA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx).
- WinDbg is also not very good at seeing which methods are called. It is good in displaying callstacks at a certain point in time, but not in logging them *over* time.You might want an API logger such as [Rohitab API monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).
- Since it is about a third party add-in, you'll probably not be able to get the symbols (if not provided by the developer). That means you cannot get the names of the methods. So even if you find the bottleneck, you'll not be able to name it.
- After all, what would you do when you have identified the bottleneck? Since you don't have the source code, there's probably not much you could change to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use ProcessMonitor and ProcessExplorer to see what is performing slowly. With the latter you can find which threads are taking CPU, and with the former you can see what IO operations the process is doing that might be taking a long time. You can compare it to Outlook running without the plugin to see what is normal.